# Jenkins Pipeline to test iOS app on multiple simulators and sdk versions

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline

I've build Jenkinsfile for multibranch-pipeline as on this gist: https://gist.github.com/nysander/0911f439bca7e046c765c0dc79e35e9f

My problem is that I want to automate testing on multiple simulators and multiple iOS SDK versions. To make this work I make a lot of duplication in attached code.

Is there any way to make this work in loop and pull list of simulators / SDK's to test from some library, array, etc?

The other thing is that testing as in gist is made in sequence (when I made it parallel it broke - something like Xcode database locked)

Other issue is that tests on tests results summary are shown now 3 times every test, and if some fail on one simulator/SDK I have no idea how to know on which SDK it failed.

Any comments and help appreciated, also if such workflow is bad from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I used to develop unit tests on Jenkins, running on multiple simulators. I came up with this https://github.com/plu/pxctest allow me to run testing in parallel, saving time as well. In your case it should be multiple simulators with different SDKs.

Regarding the summary, maybe you can export environment variables to tag every test.

Hope it helps!

Comment: unfortunately pxctest is marked as deprecated for now